# Protected questions - doesn't association bonus apply?

Tags: support

I haven't answered/asked any questions yet on Lifehacks.SE, but I crossed the 200 rep milestone on another site(SFF.SE) a few months ago, so I have 101 reputation.

However, I am not able to answer protected questions. I haven't paid very close attention but technically I should be allowed to answer these questions.

This is the said question: [How do I stop cars from tailgating?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6613/how-do-i-stop-cars-from-tailgating)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> doesn't association bonus apply?

No. As can be seen in [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/208518):

> Users with 10 or more reputation can answer a protected question. However, **the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check**, so you must have earned 10 or more reputation *on that specific site* to answer a protected question.